# jQuery - text() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

Being fairly new to jquery and javascript I can't seem to understand how the .text() method really works. I read through the jQuery documentation but still can't figure it out.

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        var currentElement = $(".artist")[i];
        var currentArtist = currentElement.text;
        console.log(currentElement);
        console.log(currentArtist);
    }
```

currentArtist returns "undefined" in the console. It works fine on the $(".artist") alone, but not when I use the [i] or anything additional for that matter. What am I missing here? How else could I grab a text value inside a selector?

Comment: Try `$('.artist').eq(i);`

Comment: See [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/). Using brackets on a jQuery object is equivalent to calling that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `[]` operator on jQuery object you're accessing the raw element node that was found by jQuery. This raw element doesn't have the jQuery methods anymore, nor a `text` property.

If you want to get single element from jQuery object and keep the jQuery wrapper, use `eq` method.

```
var artistElement = $(".artist").eq(i);
artistElement.text(); // gets the text content of the element
```

The code you've posted is also not very optimized. For instance, with every loop iteration you're searching the document over and over again for elements with class `artist`. Better to cache that search result in a variable before performing the loop. And if the loop iterates over all `.artist` elements, you can use jQuery's `each` method.

```
$(".artist").each(function () {
    var artist = $(this); // this poits to the raw element thus wrapping into jQuery object
    console.log(artist.text());
});
```

Comment: .eq() worked perfectly. Thank you very much, understood everything perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentArtist = currentElement.text;
```

Should be:

```
var currentArtist = currentElement.text();
```

Comment: I've tried either way. With the parentheses it just throws an error, that "undefined is not a function"

Comment: currentArtist points to a raw node. It doesn't neither have text method nor a text property.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$(".artist").each(function(i,val){

    var currentArtist = $(val).text();
    console.log(val);
    console.log(currentArtist);
});
```

`$(".artist")` produce a jQuery object that could be like this:

> [div, div, div, div, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init, context: document, selector: ".artist"...]

So the result of `$(".artist")[i]` is a `HTMLElement` and do not have a `text` method, that's why you're getting `undefined`

Also [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a function and may be followed with ()

But if you want to keep the for loop you can do

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    var currentElement = $(".artist")[i];
    var currentArtist = $(currentElement).text();
    console.log(currentElement);
    console.log(currentArtist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` shows the text of an html element or set of html elements that would be visible to the user.